# jQuery not loading in Webpack 2

Tags: jquery, webpack-2

I am trying to include jQuery as part of my Webpack 2 build, and for whatever reason unless I add it as a `<script>` tag in my index.html it doesn't seem to get recognized.

I have done

```
require('jquery')
```

in the files that require it and

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery'
})
```

in my webpack.config.js

as well as

```
loaders: [
{ test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose-loader?jQuery!expose-loader?$' }
]
```

I can see it is in the webpack build

```
bundle.js  2.76 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
[2] ./~/lodash/index.js 408 kB {0} [built]
[8] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 268 kB {0} [built]
```

But unless I declare it in my index.html it doesn't seem to recognize it.  What am I missing?

Comment: similar error I am also getting :(